# Does ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview 1 (or the eventual RTM) supports .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been looking for information regarding if the third version of ASP.NET MVC will support .NET 3.5 or not.

I haven't been able to find anything that either confirms it or denies it.

Comment: Good news, time to upgrade to .NET 4.0 :-)

Comment: Bad news! My company won't upgrade servers in a looong time. So its MVC 2 for me

Comment: Damn you cooperate environment. Reminds me of the time I had to fight for LINQ.

Comment: @Henrik, totally agree. Damn corporate rules, they all suck badly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Some parts of ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview are heavily tied to .NET 4.

> > **System Requirements**
> >     Supported Operating Systems:Windows 7;Windows Server 2003;Windows Server 2008;Windows Vista
> >
> > .NET 4, ASP.NET 4, Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 are required to use certain parts of this feature.

For further reference: [Comment by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx#7574465) Microsoft VP .NET Framework
*(direct link to the comment doesn't seem to work)*

> > *The changes all look great, Scott. But do you need Visual Studio 2010 for MVC3 or will it work in 2008?*
> >
> > ASP.NET MVC 3 takes a dependency on .NET 4 (for a lot of the features I listed above), so you do need VS 2010 since that is the only version of VS that works with .NET 4.  You can though use Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (which is free) if you don't have VS 2010 installed.
> >
> > Hope this helps,
> >
> > Scott

Comment: No. it won't change for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In Scott Hanselman's interview with Phil Haack, Phil Haack stated that ASP.NET MVC 3 would be .NET 4.0 only.

From the transcript:

> **Scott Hanselman:**  So does this mean that there's  no using MVC 3.0
>   outside of .NET 4.0?
>
> **Phil Haack:**  Correct.
>
> **Scott Hanselman**:  Okay.  So 2.0 people can keep  doing their thing but
>   MVC 3.0 is a more than just a  gentle
>   nudge in the direction of moving
>   towards .NET 
>   4.0.
>
> **Phil Haack:**  Correct and Visual Studio 
>   2010.  So you won't be able to build MVC 3.0 apps  using Visual Studio
>   2008.
>
> [ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview 1 with Phil Haack](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=242)

Answer (score 2):

No, the first comment by Scott Guthrie in this post says it requires ASP.Net 4
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx